# Extra tables created by Entity Framework Core for relationships

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying out ASP.NET Core with Postgres, and I noticed that when I add a foreign key constraint to my Entity Framework Core model, I'm getting an extra table.

For example:

```
namespace blog.Models;

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public required string Username { get; set; }
}
```

```
namespace blog.Models;

public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public required string Text { get; set; }
    public required User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I apply migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add migrate1 -c UserContext
dotnet ef database update -c UserContext
dotnet ef migrations add migrate2 -c PostContext
dotnet ef database update -c PostContext
```

I expect two tables, `Users` and `Posts`, but instead, I get `Users`, `Posts`, and `Post`.

[When I look at the relationship diagram on datagrip, the `Posts` table references the `User` table, but the `Users` table is by itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss5UW.png)

I tried doing the migrations one by one.

I also manually created two tables and then used `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to see why I'm getting a third table, and I saw fluent api in the generated context, which I'm not familiar with.

Is it possible to just have two tables and then just point one of them to the other without using fluent api?

If it helps, these are how I setup the contexts:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace blog.Models;

public class UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace blog.Models;

public class PostContext(DbContextOptions<PostContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Why have you declared to contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) for pointing out the separately declared contexts. Putting them together into one context fixed it.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace blog.Models;

public class Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

No idea why it works, but it works.